# How to apply .class property on Class with type parameter

Tags: java, class, types

**In short**

If A and B are 2 class, the only problem is `A.class` works but `A<B>.class` doesn't.

**In Detail**

I am very new to Java and I am trying to apply .class property on a class like `ArrayList<String>`. Please note there can be anything in place of ArrayList.
If I have a normal class like "public class Student", then I can simply write

```
Class<Student> classType = Student.class;
```

But if I have class like `A<B>`, then I **can't** simply write

```
Class<ArrayList<Student>> classType = ArrayList<Student>.class;
```

this doesn't compile. How to get `Class<ArrayList<Student>>` from ArrayList

I have tried doing

```
var classType = new ArrayList<Student>().getClass();
```

but here the type of classType is `Class<? extends ArrayList>`

But I want the type of classType as `Class<ArrayList<Student>>` How to get that?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

"Type erasure ensures that no new classes are created for parameterized types; consequently, generics incur no runtime overhead."